# Exception thrown while setting 0.0 decimal value to c# Decimal object

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this class:

```
public class PlaylistMessageBindingModel
{   
    //Other non-important fields     
    public Decimal Duration { get; set; }
}
```

I am instantiating an object of this class and read values out of a database with a data reader:

```
while (innerReader.Read())
{
    var playlistMsg = new PlaylistMessageBindingModel();
    playlistMsg.Duration = (Decimal)reader["size_time"];
}
```

But when it hits the `.Duration` line of code, it throws an Exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in MyDll.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: size_time
```

The value column in the database is `decimal(6, 3)`. I'm guessing it might have to do with the fact that the value coming out of the database is 0.000, but if that is the case, I'm not sure how to deal with that. I'd appreciate any observations.

Comment: We need more information. What's the inner exception, for example?

Comment: The inner exception is null :\

Comment: Have you checked the type of `reader["size_time"]`?  `reader["size_time"].GetType().Name`

Comment: Now its throwing an IndexOutofRangeException {"size_time"} when I set that snippet above to a string.

Comment: Did you make sure that when reading `size_time` there is a value available?

Comment: Can you show us the SQL used to read the data?  Are you sure `size_time` is included in the select part of the SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
while (innerReader.Read())
{
    var playlistMsg = new PlaylistMessageBindingModel();
    playlistMsg.Duration = reader.GetDecimal["size_time"];
}
```

Also very useful [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when you stare at your own code for too long...

I failed to notice a subtle difference in my reader objects. Above this section of code, I have instantiated a reader called `reader`. Further down the code, I instantiated `innerReader`. So when I was trying to set the duration, I have `while (innerReader.Read())` and inside that code block I'm trying `playlistMsg.Duration = (Decimal)reader["size_time"];` but it should be `(Decimal)innerReader["size_time"]`. After changing the code, I got my intended result.